# Has many relation on a table with a plural name. NameError (uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a table called `activities_dates` which I store the `activities`'s events in through a `has_many` relation.
I got it somewhat working because I can retrieve the values, but saving them I am running in `NameError (uninitialized constant ActivityDate::Activities):`

**Migration:**

```
create_table :activities_dates do |t|
      t.references :activities, foreign_key: true, index: true
      t.date :event_date
      t.timestamps
      t.datetime :deleted_at, index: true
end
```

**Model:**

```
activity.rb
class Activity < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :activities_dates, :foreign_key => "activities_id", :class_name => "ActivityDate"   



activity_date.rb
class ActivityDate < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activities
  acts_as_paranoid
  self.table_name = "activities_dates"
end
```

In my form I am passing an array of `recurring_event_date` and then do a for each statement to create them. This is where the actual "Name Error" occurs.

**Form: (I have a Javascript function that adds in multiple recurring event inputs, hence the array)**

```
<% @activity.activities_dates.each_with_index do |event, idx| %>
    <div class="form-group classes-field-one-time date-field">
       <input class="form-control" type="date" name="activity[recurring_event_date][]" id="activity_event_date" value="<%= event.event_date %>">
       <button class="remove-recurring-date btn-danger"> X </button>
     </div>
<% end %>
```

**Activities Controller @ Update Function**

```
def update
 if can? :update @activity
   respond_do |format|
    if @activity.update(activity_params.except(:recurring_event_date))
        activity_params[:recurring_event_date].each do |event|
          @activity.activities_dates.create(:event_date => event) #ERROR HERE
        end
```

I believe I just have some naming conventions wrong because I will want to save them via `@activity model`

Comment: It should be `ActivityDates` you do not pluralize both unless this is a HABTM. and it would be `Activity has_many :activity_dates` and `ActivityDate belongs_to :activity` because it can only belong to 1 (singular)

Comment: @engineersmnky I tried that and now I do not get the error although it does it save in that table. Any suggestions?

Comment: @engineersmnky `even = @activity.activity_dates.new(:event_date => event)`
            `even.save`

Comment: @engineersmnky The error in the console is `@messages={:activity=>["must exist"]}, @details={:activity=>[{:error=>:blank}]}`

Comment: Use `build` instead to create the relationship e.g. `even = @activity.activity_dates.build(event_date: event)`. Also make sure `@activity` persisted at this point e.g. not a "new" activity.

Comment: @engineersmnky Works now! Thank you

Comment: @engineersmnky I had to add `optional: true` to the `belongs_to` in the activity_date... then it saved no problem.

Comment: if you "had to add" that then chances are the ActivityDate is not connected to the Activity at all which defeats the purpose if I'm not mistaken